# Differentiating values with common names in a query

Tags: asp.net, sql

This is a generic question. I have a query to get names of students and their Roll Number from a table. In some cases two or more students have same name. In that case alone i want to display their names along with their roll numbers. In other cases i want to display their names alone. How can the query be written for that? Is that possible in SQL or else i want to perform the checking operation in code behind only?

Sql Query:

```
Select Name as Student_Name,RollNo from Students
```

Comment: I can't help thinking this is UI logic and so should be in the UI code not the db...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in SQL you need to do something like the following:

```
select
  case when m.Name is null then s.Name
  else s.Name + ' ' + s.RollNo
  end as Name
from Students s
left join
(
  select Name from Students
  group by Name
  having count(*) > 1
 ) m on s.name = m.name
```

However I'm going to attempt a controversial answer because I feel this is UI logic and should be kept in the UI (you've tagged the question with ASP.NET so I can only assume you have a UI). I'm assuming C#.

Inside your Student class I'd do the following:

```
public override ToString()
{
  return this.Student_Name;
}

public string GetDisplayName(IEnumerable<Student> otherStudentsInList)
{
  if(otherStudentsInList.Contains(this.ToString())
  {
    return string.Concat(this.ToString(), " ", this.RollNo);
  }
  else
  {
    return this.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: ya it can be solved by using C# code. But if i get the solution in SQL Query it would be more useful. If there is no way of doing this in query then i have no other option rather than going for c# code.

Comment: You know your context, I've added the SQL (obviously I don't have your schema but I believe it's right)

Answer (score 3):

Write a query with a CASE, and in the case condition GROUP BY name and if HAVING COUNT > 1, select name and roll number. In the ELSE statement just query for names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query

```
Select Student_Name,

Case When Student_Name=(Select Student_Name from Students group by Student_Name having 
Count(*) > 1) THEN  RollNo

ELSE NULL

END RollNo

from Students
```

Happy Coding